# How to use the tkinter variable in another code?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have this code `test1.py`:

```py
from tkinter import *
def key(event):
    return event.keysym
w = Tk()
w.geometry('150x150')
w.mainloop()
```

How to use a variable `event.keysym` in `test2.py` code, if the `test1.py` code imported at `test2.py` code?

I used this code `test2.py`:

```py
import test1
key = test1.key()
print(key)
```

But this does not display the name of the pressed key in the code console `test2.py`.

Comment: Why do you think it should return a keysym? For one, the `key` method takes a parameter but you are calling it without a parameter, so you should be getting an error when you call `test1.key()`.

Comment: But what value should the `event` parameter have?

Comment: Only you can answer that. You're the one that created it. It looks like it's designed to be called from a binding, but you're calling it directly. It's unclear what you're trying to achieve.